# groupby with dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregation

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,1, 1], 'time_stamp_date':['12','12', '12', '14', '14'], 'sth':['col1','col1', 'col2','col2', 'col3']})

d   time_stamp_date sth
0   1   12         col1
1   2   12         col1
2   3   12         col2
3   1   14         col2
4   1   14         col3
```

and I would like to get the following dataframe. So for each column in `sht_list`I would like to check if it appears in sth for a specific `id` and `time_stamp_date`.

```
id  time_stamp_date sth col1 col2 col3  col4
0   1   12          col1    1   0    0    0
1   2   12          col1    1   0    0    0
2   3   12          col2    0   1    0    0
3   1   14          col2    0   1    1    0
4   1   14          col3    0   1    1    0
```

I can do it like this

```
df_out = df.assign(**{col: df.groupby(['id','time_stamp_date']).sth.transform(
                                                            lambda x: (x==col).any()).astype(int) 
                                      for col in sht_list})
```

but I would like to use only groupby (without transform and then having to use drop_duplicates())
but the below doesn't work because all columns will be named the same ().
The error that I get is `SpecificationError: Function names must be unique, found multiple named <lambda>`.

```
df_out = df.groupby(['id','time_stamp_date'])[['sth']].agg({lambda x: (x==col).any().astype(int) 
                                                      for col in sht_list})
```

Is it possible to make the above code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to think in terms of the `Index` for this one. You already know where the values for your dummies exist so you can rely on index manipulations and filling values that don't exist.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,2,3,1, 1],
    'time_stamp_date':['12','12', '12', '14', '14'],
    'sth':['col1','col1', 'col2','col2', 'col3']
})
sth_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

out = (
    pd.Series(data=1, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df))
    .unstack('sth', fill_value=0)
    .reindex(
        # index=… here is only if you want row order from original data
        index=pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['id', 'time_stamp_date']].drop_duplicates()),
        columns=sth_list, fill_value=0
    )
)
print(out)
sth                 col1  col2  col3  col4
id time_stamp_date                        
1  12                  1     0     0     0
2  12                  1     0     0     0
3  12                  0     1     0     0
1  14                  0     1     1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation).

For that pass the column name to use in the dictionary, also change your function to have both the static column and the string to compare to as parameters:

```
df_out = (df.groupby(['id','time_stamp_date'], as_index=False, sort=False)
            .agg(**{col: ('sth', lambda x, col=col: (x==col).any().astype(int))
                    for col in sht_list})
         )
```

Output:

```
   id time_stamp_date  col1  col2  col3  col4
0   1              12     1     0     0     0
1   2              12     1     0     0     0
2   3              12     0     1     0     0
3   1              14     0     1     1     0
```

Alternatively, with [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df_out = (df[['id', 'time_stamp_date']]
            .join(df['sth'].str.get_dummies()
                  .reindex(columns=sht_list, fill_value=0)
                 )
            .groupby([df['id'], df['time_stamp_date']],
                     as_index=False, sort=False)
            .max()
         )
```

Comment: This gives me this error: TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg' I have pandas version 0.23.4

Comment: @corianne1234 which pandas version do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which is based on [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
(pd.pivot_table(
    df, index=['id', 'time_stamp_date'], columns='sth', 
    aggfunc=lambda x: min(1, len(x)), fill_value=0)
 .reindex(columns=[f'col{i}' for i in range(1, 5)], fill_value=0)
 .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
 .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   id time_stamp_date  col1  col2  col3  col4
0   1              12     1     0     0     0
1   1              14     0     1     1     0
2   2              12     1     0     0     0
3   3              12     0     1     0     0
```

Comment: This doesn't actually match OP's desired result

Comment: I guess, @Nick, my updated answer solves the problem posed by the OP. Thanks for your co-operation!